# Using fitted GLM model to simulate y's from new x-values

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, simulation

I have a fitted GLM model: `m1=glm(y~x,family=poisson,data=data)`.  I would like to use this fitted model to simulate new data but `simulate(m1,nsim=1)` results only in y's for the original x-values used to fit the model.  Can the simulate function be used to generate y's from new x-values?

Comment: From the help, it doesn't look like it, but you could do it with `rpois`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this.  First make some fake data to test on

```
x <- rnorm(100) 
y <- rpois(rep(1,100), exp(x)) ## poisson regression with slope=1
## fit model
m1 <- glm(y ~ x,family=poisson)
```

Now decide on your new x points

```
new.data <- data.frame(x=seq(-3,3,.1))
```

get the predicted expected value of `y` for these points

```
mu.y <- predict(m1, newdata=new.data, type='response')
```

and generate `k` sets of simulated `y` at these new points. Your question has k=1 but we may as well be general.

```
sim.y <- replicate(k, rpois(rep(1, length(mu.y)), mu.y))
```

Now `sim.y` is a matrix with as many rows as `new.data` and `k` columns, each containing a possible set of `y` values assuming the model is correct.